# Значення слова "Чарний, чарна, чарне"

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми, діалекти, лемківський-діалект

Колись давно я стикався з таким словом і пам'ятав його значення, і навіть використав в одному з віршів, а зараз забув його значення, це було щось діалектне, чи то гуцульське, чи лемківське, чи бойківське, але не можу згадати, з якого саме діалекту.
Хтось знає, де є словники діалектів карпатських або де можна глянути значення цього прикметника "Чарний, чарна, чарне"?

Comment: Може, від _чар_? Тобто фактично рідковживаний варіант слова _чарівний_?

Comment: А може *вода - водний*, *чари - чарний*?

Comment: Є ще варіант, що від слова «[чара](http://sum.in.ua/s/chara)» (тобто як «[чарка](http://sum.in.ua/s/charka)»), але чомусь мені здається, що то навряд.

Comment: Ну й остання версія — варіант вимови слова «[чорний](http://sum.in.ua/s/chornyj)». Спочатку мені здавалося, що навряд, але, враховуючи, що польською «чорний» буде «[czarny](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/czarny#Adjective)», то цілком може бути…

Comment: А, ні, ще «найостанніша»: варіант вимови слова «[чва́рний](http://sum.in.ua/s/chvarnyj)» (від «[чва́ри](http://sum.in.ua/s/chvary)», але, як не дивно, позначає не «сварливий» чи «суперечливий», а «бурхливий»).

Comment: @Sasha, я сподіваюся, що ви усвідомлюєте, що інші дописувачі, які знають правильну відповідь (і я знаю також), вже не стануть її писати після того, як ви її озвучили у своїй (напів-)відповіді у вигляді коментаря.

Answer (score 1):

Це "чорний"/"чорна", вимова наближена до польської - ймовірно лемківський діалект.

(польською «чорний» буде «czarny»)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].